# Updated Chrome but old version still launches

Tags: google-chrome, updates

I updated Google Chrome to the latest version but it keeps on launching the old version when ever I open it. Can anyone tell me how to solve this? I have Windows 10.

Comment: How did you upgrade it? Sounds like it actually didn't.

Comment: Through official site

Comment: I thought Chrome should update itself in Windows... how are you checking what version is installed? What version do you have now & want version do you want to update to?

Comment: I have 63 but when ever I open it shows 58

Comment: That's what menu -> About Chrome says, always returns to 58.something? Are you using a regular consumer version of windows 10, on a regular computer/laptop? Or is there some "master program" that controls what gets installed & upgraded? Or you're running something like a read-only windows that resets all changes when it reboots?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **exact** version numbers you are referring to when you say "old" and "new". Based on one of the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1280835/updated-chrome-but-old-version-still-launches/1280839#comment1891953_1280839) you made on an answer it seems you may be causing confusion by using these terms casually.

Answer (score 1):

If updating Chrome fails, simply uninstall it through Windows, then reinstall from scratch. This will ensure the old version is completely removed. Installing from Google's website will ensure the latest version is installed.

If you don't sign in to Chrome to save your settings, be sure to manually save them before doing this to avoid losing your settings.

Comment: I tried that too but it launches old version only

Comment: @user9151324 That's pretty much impossible. How are you uninstalling Chrome? Did you make sure it was gone from your computer after doing this?

Comment: I uninstalled by going to control panel and I am 100% sure its removed then I install new version and when I open it, the old version is launched.

Comment: @user9151324 By definition, if you fully removed the old version, there is no "old" version to launch. Either you're not removing the old version, or perhaps more likely, what you're installing is actually the old version. Are you certain of the version number of the new install?

Comment: Can you tell me the method to remove the old version completely

Comment: Search `add remove programs` in Start. But it does sound like you did that.

Comment: I did this I think I should try uninstaller software

Comment: @user9151324 won’t make a difference if you do, uninstalled software uses the exact same mechanism, you are already using.

Comment: I tried but nothing happening I deleted each and every old chrome file and installed new version but it launches old version of chrome.

Comment: Right-click on the Chrome shortcut to find exactly what exe it’s running, then uninstall Chrome and make sure that exe is gone. Also old versions of Chrome could be installed outside of the AppData directory, so also look for Chrome in ProgramFiles, etc.

Comment: OK I'll try it again

Answer (score -1):

First, it's possible that you maybe downloaded the new version but have yet to install it. Make sure that any downloaded files have been installed.

Second, make sure that you have the correct application to launch from. Sometimes a new installation can leave an old version on your computer. Look through your files to make sure that there are no other Google Chrome applications in your files. If there is, delete the older version and open the new one.

Third, simply download the newest version again and make sure to follow through with all the installation guidelines.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have installed it properly. As soon as my laptop starts I open the chrome it shows new version but once I close the chrome and open it again it shows old version. I don't know what to do how to remove the old version. I tried many ways but none of them worked .

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to *downgrade* Chrome to an older version, that just happens to be "new to you" since it's not the "old one" that's installed now? Maybe it's just successfully updating itself automatically?

Comment: @user9151324: You said, “it keeps on launching the old version when ever I open it” (in the question); now you are saying something different.   People won’t be able to help you if you don’t give us consistent information.

Comment: I found this now only so only I told that now